# accessing a <p> in Watir, which doesn't have attribute

Tags: ruby, cucumber, watir

I have this html code.

```
<div class="main" data-reactid=".0.2.1.1">
  <div contenteditable="true" data-reactid=".0.2.1.1.0" autocomplete="off">
    <p>
       <br>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have to write in

tag. For this I wrote as:

`paragraph(:article_title) {div_element(:class=>'main').div(:index=>1).paragraph(:index=>1)}`

but it is giving an error. I don't understand what is wrong in this.

Comment: It would help if you share the error that you are getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of problems:

1. Watir uses a 0-based index. As a result, `div(:index=>1)` actually means to find the 2nd div tag. As this does not exist, you will get an unable to locate element error.
2. `div` and `paragraph` are not methods defined in the page-object gem. You will get deprecation errors when you try to use them. It should be `div_element` and `paragraph_element` respectively.

Try doing:

`paragraph(:article_title) {div_element(:class=>'main').div_element(:index=>0).paragraph_element(:index=>0)}`

More simply, since `:index => 0` is implied:

`paragraph(:article_title){div_element(:class=>'main').div_element.paragraph_element}`

As there is only one paragraph element, you could further simplify it to:

```
paragraph(:article_title) {div_element(:class=>'main').paragraph_element}
```

Comment: There is only one `<p>`. So shouldn't be at `index=>0`?. In first example.

Comment: Also writing text in it is not working. I tried `self.idea_title_element = "Hello World"` and `self.idea_title = "Hello World"`

Comment: Sorry, yes it should be `:index=>0` (fixed).

Comment: The accessor does not create any methods for setting the values of a `div` or `p` tag. You will likely need to do `self.idea_title_element.send_keys("Hello World")`. I believe you actually want to target the `div` rather than the `p` tag in this case (as the `div` is the one with the `contenteditable` attribute).

Comment: But in another class where in `text_field(:username, :id=>"username")`, here I didnt use `send_keys`. I used `self.username = "auto_user"`. So why not here?

Comment: Each accessor adds a different set of methods to the page object - ie `text_field` and `paragraph` do two different things. You can see the methods added by each accessor in the [documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/cheezy/page-object/master/PageObject/Accessors).

Comment: Sorry, but I already visited this DOC, before asking the question on SO. So, where is it written that, which locator will have send_keys and which doesnt.?

Comment: `send_keys` is a method of the Element, so all elements will have it. See the [element documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/cheezy/page-object/master/PageObject/Platforms/WatirWebDriver/Element#send_keys-instance_method).

Comment: Thanks for your patience and support.